# Decompose into Partial Fraction. Image Added.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, partial-fractions

[image: Decompose into Partial Fraction]

I really had no idea how to write these questions out without copying and pasting them onto here, so I am sorry for that..I hope adding a picture is fine. I would appreciate any kind of help, and if you dont mind suggesting a useful website, or video that can explain these problems to me. Thank you

Comment: A quick bit of googling gives [this](http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/ode/laplace/pf/pf.html) tutorial on the partial fraction method. Read through it and give the question a try.

Answer (score 0):

It can be decomposed into the form
$$\frac{x^2}{(x+\alpha)(x-\beta)^2} = \frac{\lambda}{x+\alpha} + \frac{\mu}{x-\beta} + \frac{\nu}{(x-\beta)^2}$$
which means
$$ \lambda(x-\beta)^2 + \mu(x+\alpha)(x-\beta) + \nu(x+\alpha) = x^2
$$
It can be written as a set of equations
$$\begin{align*}
\lambda + \mu &= 1 \\
-2\beta\lambda + (\alpha - \beta)\mu + \nu &= 0 \\
\beta^2\lambda - \alpha\beta\mu + \alpha\nu &= 0
\end{align*}$$
Solving for $\lambda, \mu, \nu$ will give you the correct decomposition. (I used CAS here)
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
-2\beta & \alpha-\beta & 1 & 0 \\
\beta^2 & -\alpha\beta & \alpha & 0
\end{array}\right]
\rightarrow
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{\alpha^2}{(\alpha+\beta)^2} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{\beta^2+2\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{\beta^2}{\alpha+\beta}
\end{array}\right]
$$
Hence
$$ \lambda = \frac{\alpha^2}{(\alpha+\beta)^2}, \mu = -\frac{\beta^2+2\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2}, \nu = \frac{\beta^2}{\alpha+\beta}$$

Comment: Ok I understand the first two parts clearly...But what exactly do u mean set them to set of equations and solve them? How do you solve that? I am used to dealing with numbers instead of Letters like Beta and Alpha so I am confused. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Anyone?? I still cant figure this out. Please help. I set x=1. so x^2=A(1-beta) + B(1 + alpha)---> 1= 1A- betaA + 1B + alphaB...then what? I dont get the next step please help

Comment: if u dont mind?

Comment: @user281364 $x$ is not involved in the three linear equations. These three equations are used to solve for the coefficients $a, b, c$ in $ax^2 + bx + c$.

Comment: Ok,so now i Just have to solve that last part?